# Is every prime ideal in $\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty}{k}$ maximal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, filters

Suppose k is a algebraic closed field, is every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in the product ring $\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty}{k}$ maximal?

Comment: Just like to toss out here that you can drop the condition that $k$ be algebraically closed. Martin's suggestion that von Neumann regular rings are the thing to look at is pretty much optimal in the sense that VNR rings are characterized as the rings without nonzero nilpotent elements whose prime ideals are maximal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. More generally, define a commutative ring $R$ to be von Neumann regular if for every $x \in R$ we have $x^2 | x$. Clearly this property is preserved by arbitrary products, as well as quotients, and fields have this property (more generally, one can show that $R$ is von Neumann regular iff every localization of $R$ is a field). If $R$ is an integral domain which is von Neumann regular, then $R$ is a field (just cancel $x$ in $x^2 y = x$). It follows that every prime ideal of a von Neumann regular ring is maximal (in fact one can show that $R$ is von Neumann regular iff $R$ is reduced and $\dim(R)=0$).

In particular, every prime ideal in a product of fields is maximal. There are more direct ways to prove this. In fact, one can classify all ideals, they correspond to filters on the index set. Then we observe that prime filters are exactly the ultrafilters.

Comment: What is the correspondence between ideals of the product of fields and filters of the index set?

Comment: @anon He is assuming $x^2$ divides $x$, which is that condition called *von Neumann regular*. In the case of product of fields because everything non-zero divides everything, and zero divides (is a multiple of) zero.

Comment: Deleted previous comments. I understand now. Just being silly.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg Can we say more about the quotient field? Can it be not k?

Comment: Sure. The maximal ideals with quotient field $k$ correspond to the principal ultrafilters. But there are a lot more ultrafilters.