# When is a local, reduced, (commutative) ring an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

**Question**

I am wondering whether or not it is true that *if $A$ is a reduced ring, then 
is it the case that the localization of $A$ at any of its prime ideals is an integral domain?*

**Discussion**

Recall that $A$ is reduced if it contains no nonzero nilpotents, i.e. $Nil(A)=\{0\}$.

I have already shown the following two facts:

1. A ring $A$ being reduced is a local property, i.e. $A$ is reduced if and only if the localization of $A$ at any prime ideal is reduced.
2. $A$ reduced does not imply $A$ is an integral domain (in general).

The counter example I used to prove $2$ was $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Unfortunately, in this case all the localizations at prime ideals are integral domains, and they seem to be in every example I can think of. More generally, one could ask the question (since localizations are local rings), when is a reduced local ring an integral domain?

If anyone had a good idea for a counterexample to the original question (or a proof if it is true-although I doubt this since being an integral domain seems much stronger than being reduced), that would be much appreciated.

This is one of 12 parts to a question which I had on my midterm a few weeks ago, and the only part I have not figured out of that question

Comment: @user121097 since all localizations are local rings finding when a reduced local ring is an integral domain is stronger than the specific question. Also as I mentioned above I just find the general question interesting and would still be interested on hearing more about it. My thought process when attempting to answer the original question led me to the more general question which encompasses everything I  wanted to know.

Comment: Sorry to bump this old question, but I wanted to point out that _regular_ local rings are guaranteed to be integral domains - "regular" meaning the minimum number of generators of the unique maximal ideal is equal to the Krull dimension. For instance, DVRs are integral domains (some definitions assume this by default, but it's actually superfluous: any commutative Noetherian local ring whose maximal ideal is principal is a domain).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true. The ring $k[x,y]/(xy)$ is reduced but the localization at $(x,y)$ is not an integral domain. For instance, because $xy = 0$ ***in the localization*** but $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$.

Comment: I think it is an integral domain if you localize at $(x)$. The image of $y$ is a unit. But localization at $(x,y)$ provides an example.

Comment: How do we know that $k[x,y]/(xy)$ is reduced? Edit: I see that $k[x,y]$ has no nilpotent elements so the nilpotent elements of $k[x,y]/(xy)$ are precisely those elements of $k[x,y]$ which belong to the radical of $(xy)$

Answer (score 4):

There is not a whole lot to say here. You are given that $\{0\}$ is semiprime, and you are asking when it is prime. You could say that $R$ is a domain iff $\{0\}$ is primary. fpqc's example demonstrates this nicely since $(xy)$ is a semiprime but not prime ideal of $k[x,y]$ and also not in the localization at $(x)$ or $(y)$.

Locality never really comes into play.

The reason you did not find any counterexamples using $\Bbb Z/(n)$ is that this ring is only reduced when $n$ is squarefree, and for each such $n$ the ring is von Neumann regular, and the localizations at prime ideals [are all fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566103/29335).